# Reindex Search API indexes for Behat testing

Tags: 7, testing

I tried to use index the newly created contents to be able to test a page, but the problem is most of the times the tests fails, because the indexing process not finished yet until the contents starts checking. (i.e. if I stop before pageload with a breakpoint the testing, then the next steps always pass)

Method 1:

```
$search_api_index = search_api_index_load('SEARCH_API_INDEX_ID');
search_api_index_items($search_api_index);
```

Method 2:

```
search_api_cron();
```

The question, how can I call the indexing to wait until it's fully indexed before it goes forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultimate solution is `$search_api_index->server()->commit()` which needed because, there's a commit delay which you can set inside the `solrconfig.xml` and this delay cause the problem. (Or you can just `sleep(1)` your code, but that's not flexible at all and ugly...)